# multiple AND condition in laravel with null or not null value

Tags: php

select * from users where id=1 AND id=2 AND id=3

if (id =1) is not found or null then it should fetch data using other two AND conditions.

for example, select * from users where id=2 AND id=3.

How can i do this in laravel. Please help

I have done this in sql server like below, but i can't do this in laravel

@var=null

select * from users where (id=1 OR @var is null) AND (id=2 OR @var is null) AND (id=3 OR @var is null)

Comment: It's not clear what information contains \@var: is it a 'flag' or does contains the id to search?
In your example if \@var is NULL all rows are selected from the table.

Finally, in Laravel the *id* is usually the primary key, that means tha it could never be 1 AND 2 AND 3 at the same time

So, with your query, there are two types of result: all the rows or no rows...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like below:

```
$users = User:where(function($query) {
    $query->where('id', 1)->orWhereNull('var');
})->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('id', 2)->orWhereNull('var');
})->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('id', 3)->orWhereNull('var');
})->get()
```

Comment: Actuallay my problem is how i can filter data in where clause by using multiple independent dropdown. And how i can use (1=1) condition in where clause if any dropdown is not selected or null value.